# Merge Two Data Frames of Different Sizes and Apply Formula

Tags: r

I have two data frames that look like this:

```
Name    Total
 A        43
 B        56
 C        98
 ...      ....
```

And

```
Name    col1    col2    col3    col4    ...
 A       2       3       4        0
 B       0       4       0        0    
 C       3       0       0        3
...     ...     ...     ...      ...
```

I'd like to combine the two frames, matching on the name columns, dividing the col1, col2, col3, etc. by the corresponding total in the first data frame and transforming it into a percentage. So the output should look like this:

```
Name    col1    col2    col3    col4    ...
 A      4.65    6.98    9.30      0
 B       0      7.14      0       0
 C      3.06      0       0     3.06
...
```

The data is fairly dynamic and I'd like to be able to run this code again as the data evolves. The first dataframe will remain the format, but the second one could have more columns in the second iteration of the data.

I've tried merging, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply division.

Comment: Try `df2[-1] <- round(100*df2[-1]/df1$Total[match(df2$Name, df1$Name)][row(df2[-1])],2)`

Comment: Perrfect! Thanks. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Thanks, then I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do this using `base R`.  One option would be to `match` the 'Name' column in the first dataset ('df1') and in the second ('df2') to get a numeric index.  Based on that index, we get the elements of 'Total' from 'df1'.  We can divide df2 excluding the 'Name' column (`df2[-1]`) by the 'Total'.  It would be helpful to have both numerator and denominator to be of equal sizes.  For that, we replicate the 'Total'.  The `row(df2[-1])` gives the row index of the dataset, which we used to replicate the elements of 'Total'.  After the division, we can multiply by 100 and `round` (if necessary) and assign the results back to the columns of 'df2' excluding the first column.

```
v1 <- df1$Total[match(df2$Name, df1$Name)]
v2 <- v1[row(df2[-1])]
df2[-1] <- round(100*df2[-1]/v2,2)
df2
#  Name col1 col2 col3 col4
#1    A 4.65 6.98  9.3 0.00
#2    B 0.00 7.14  0.0 0.00
#3    C 3.06 0.00  0.0 3.06
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), Total = c(43L, 56L, 98L
)), .Names = c("Name", "Total"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), col1 = c(2L, 0L, 3L), 
col2 = c(3L, 4L, 0L), col3 = c(4L, 0L, 0L), col4 = c(0L, 
0L, 3L)), .Names = c("Name", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result = 
  total_data_frame %>%
  inner_join(column_data_frame) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -Name, -Total) %>%
  mutate(value = value/Total*100) %>%
  spread(variable, value)
```

Explanation: gather and spread are inverse operations. They are somewhat difficult to explain, but they put all data that was gathered into one column, and reverse. They are sometimes a viable option for applying over columns, particularly if datasets are small.

Comment: Can you please add explanations?